# 'const' keyword in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Why a class member cannot have the 'const' keyword in TypeScript?

I cannot find any usefull information about it at [TypeScript documentation website](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#classes).

Comment: see this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4045

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Why a class member cannot have the 'const' keyword in TypeScript?

`const` does not imply deep immutability so the following is valid:

```
const foo:any = {};
foo.bar = 123;  // Okay
```

In that sense *readonly* makes better sense for class members and that is supported : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/readonly.html

Comment: What version of TS is `readonly` supported? It [doesn't seem to work in the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20bar%20%3D%201%3B%0A%7D).

Comment: I think maybe you wanted to write something like this-> const foo:any = { bar: 456 };  I'll delete this comment

Comment: @Aaron: `readonly` will be supported in TSC 2.0. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap

Answer (score 4):

Well my friend, from the little that I know and the test I did here, the code below will work. The "const..." needs to be outside of class, like below:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

const HEROES: any[] = [
  {id: 1, name: "Rafael Moura"},
  {id: 2, name: "Hulk"},
  {id: 3, name: "Iron Man"},
  {id: 4, name: "Spider-Man"},
  {id: 5, name: "Super-Man"},
  {id: 6, name: "Thor"},
  {id: 7, name: "Wolverine"},
  {id: 8, name: "Cyclop"},
  {id: 9, name: "Magneto"},
  {id: 10, name: "Arrow"},
  {id: 11, name: "Geen"}
]

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-heroes',
  templateUrl: './component-heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-heroes.component.css']
})

export class ComponentHeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  title = "Tour of Heros";
  heroes = HEROES;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```