# Why can't we define a const field in TypeScript class, and why static readonly is not working?

Tags: typescript, constants

I want to use `const` keyword in my program.

```
export class Constant {

    let result : string;

    private const CONSTANT = 'constant'; //Error: A class member cannot have the const keyword.

    constructor () {}

    public doSomething () {
        if (condition is true) {
           //do the needful
        }
        else
        {
            this.result = this.CONSTANT; // NO ERROR
        }


    }
}
```

**Question1**: why the class member does not have the const keyword in typescript?

**Question2**: When I use

```
static readonly CONSTANT = 'constant';
```

and assign it in

```
this.result = this.CONSTANT;
```

it displays error. why so?

I have followed this post [How to implement class constants in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265275/how-to-implement-class-constants-in-typescript) but don't get the answer why typescript is displaying this kind of error with `const` keyword.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> **Question1:** why the class member does not have the const keyword in typescript?

By design. Among other reasons, because EcmaScript6 [doesn't either](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4045).

This question is specifically answered here : ['const' keyword in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142879/const-keyword-in-typescript?rq=1)

---

> **Question2:**
>   When I use
>
> `static readonly CONSTANT = 'constant';`and assign it in
>
> `this.result = this.CONSTANT;`
>
> it displays error. why so?

If you use `static`, then you can't refer to your variable with `this`, but with the the name of the class !

```
export class Constant{

let result : string;

static readonly CONSTANT = 'constant';

constructor(){}

public doSomething(){
   if( condition is true){
      //do the needful
   }
   else
   {
      this.result = Constant.CONSTANT;
   }
}
}
```

Why ? Because `this` refers to the instance of the class to which the field / method belongs. For a static variable / method, it doesn't belong to any instance, but to the class itself (quickly simplified)